# Emacs mode for 2018+ version of PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts

I found old discussions pointing to older packages that are no longer compatible with newer PyCharm, like [Emacs+](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7906-emacs-), any suggestions what Emacsers use with modern PyCharm versions?

Comment: Did you use a recent [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) 26 ?

Comment: ........no, why